# How do i store and do calculations on the streamlit app for storing marks?

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

```py
import sys
import pandas as pd

batch_size = int(input("how many students are there in your class?"))
if batch_size > 10:
    sys.exit("Batch size cannot be greater than 10")

print(batch_size)

D={}
# Add student information
# to the dictionary
for i in range(1, batch_size + 1):
    roll = i
    marks = int(input('Enter Marks: '))
    D[roll] = marks

print(D)
df=pd.DataFrame(D)
print(df)
```

I am building this application which takes roll number of some students (`X`) and stores their corresponding marks in a dictionary (entered by the user). The dictionary is converted to a dataframe to show more columns of the dataframe. These calculations will be performed by the `streamlit` application. How can I export the result to a PDF?

I tried creating and hosting this on streamlit cloud but I could not understand how I would go about storing the marks of students and how do I take input of so many students.

Comment: Firstly - this does not look like a streamlit app. But also what is not clear from your question is whether you just want to interact with the app, and then export the results from that session to PDF, or whether you want to have a long term storage and be able to access the results from session to session.